# jquery - onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display/hide a previous/next button when a mouse over/out happens. but it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is my code.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Portfolio</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slides.jquery.js"></script>
  <script>


       $('.eachImage').on( "mouseover", function() {
         $('#prevButton').show();
       });
        </script>

      </head>

      <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <div id="container">
    <div id="example">
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <img src="imgs/test.png" width="800" height="456" class="eachImage">
            </div>
            <div id="prevButton"><a href="#" class="prev"><img src="imgs/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a></div>
            <div id="nextButton"><a href="#" class="next"><img src="imgs/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div></body>
      </html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your jQuery code inside a $(document).ready(function() ?? the image class="eachImage" is not loaded into DOM when your js code is read.

Comment: Can you define 'not working'?

Comment: Also, you could simply use `.hover` ;)

Comment: `<div id="prevButton">` and `<div class="nextButton"` you mixing ids/classes, bad idea

Comment: I edited the description. I copied&pasted the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the function to use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.eachImage').mouseover(function(){
    $('#prevButton').toggle();
    });
     });
```

I also include a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/joseluisrod/XwMzh/3/

the key is to have the style="display:block" for each button

Comment: ok, did you check the jsFiddle. did it work there? also is very important to have the code inside the document.ready and to have the css style for the displays. do you get an error message?